# STM32 HAL_CRC 16 Bit

Tags: c, stm32, hal, crc16

I try to use the `HAL_CRC` on my STM32L4 in order to calculate a 16 bit CRC, but somehow I always get the same result no matter what the input is...

The CRC init

```
hcrc.Instance = CRC;
hcrc.Init.CRCLength = CRC_POLYLENGTH_16B; //as I have a 16bit polynome
hcrc.Init.DefaultPolynomialUse = DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_DISABLE;
hcrc.Init.GeneratingPolynomial = 0x1021; //MCRF4xx polynome
hcrc.Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE; //I want to init with 0xFFFF
hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode = CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_BYTE; //input inversion
hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode = CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_ENABLE; //output inversion
hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES; //I have byte input
if (HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}
```

and then the calculation is called with

```
uint32_t result;
uint8_t pBuffer[3] = {0x33, 0x33, 0x55};
result = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc,pBuffer,3);
```

but the result is always `0xe000ed04`, I'd expect `0xC91B` for this specific case but at least it should change if a change the input. Does anyone spot an issue with this code snippet? I couldn't find any sample codes for 16bit CRC with the HAL Library.

I'm aware that the return value of `HAL_CRC_Calculate()` is a `uint32_t`, so my result would be the two lower bytes - in this case `0xed04`. At least that's my interpretation of the function description.

Comment: How do you want to calculate CRC16 from 3 bytes? It has to be divisible by 16 bits... The 3rd argument is the count of half-words - you have 3 bytes, that's 1,5 half-words, not `3`.

Comment: @KamilCuk the `CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES` flag should allow `3` to be the correct unit of input (number of bytes, not number of half words), but the issue as you point out is that the number of bytes should be divisible by 2 for a 16 bit CRC, otherwise HAL will only process `3 / 2 == 1` half word of input, or the first two bytes in this case.

Comment: So how would I then calculate the CRC16 for this input? And even if it only calculates the CRC for the first two bytes the output should still change with the input...

Comment: @po.pe To set aside `n==3` issue, how do things works for you  with `uint8_t pBuffer[4] = {0x33, 0x33, 0x55}; result = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc,pBuffer,4);`?

Comment: No, KamilCuk is incorrect. A CRC-n can be calculated on any number of bits, independent of n.

Comment: @Mark Adler, that was my impression too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation indicates that you need to enable the CRC hardware clock with `__HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_ENABLE();`. Are you doing that?

Comment: I'll check, but I thought the HAL init takes care of this...

Comment: HAL does indeed take care of this.. by giving you a function to enable the clock :) On a more serious note, make sure to check the comment at the top of corresponding source file - `stm32f4xx_hal_crc.c` for example. There's usually (always?) a "How to use this driver" section, that explains what needs to be done and in which order. In case of CRC driver, enabling the clock is actually listed there so reading that would probably save you some effort.